# React-Router DOM isn't refreshing on login. Works with manual refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can switch between login and signup pages seamlessly. However, when I log in (backend is working fine for this purpose) my DOM doesn't refresh. Is this a state/redux issue or is something else going on behind the scenes that I don't understand? My history pushes properly, but I need to manually refresh in order to see the page that I'm supposed to redirect to. Code below is my current react-router setup. I'll paste the actual repos below. (warning: you'll have to delete the rails master.key then run `bin/rails credentials:edit` to make the backend work)

I've tried different locations for the JSX for my react-router. Currently, the most successful is to locate my react-router in my App.js

```
<Router>
      {!AniTrackerAdapter.isLoggedIn() ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/register"
              render={routerProps => <SignUp {...routerProps} />}
            />

            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={routerProps => <LoginPage {...routerProps} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/anime/:id"
              component={routerProps => (
                <ShowPage {...this.props.selectedShow} {...routerProps} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/anime"
              render={routerProps => <ShowContainer {...routerProps} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </Router>
```

expected result: when /anime is pushed to history, the action anime series page loads.

actual results atm: blank screen, have to manually refresh to get the anime series page to load

edit: repos needed:

backend: https://github.com/mobrien829/ani-tracker-backend

frontend: https://github.com/mobrien829/ani-tracker